# keycloak-nodejs-connect: Could not obtain grant code: 400:Bad Request

Tags: node.js, express, jboss, keycloak

**Setup:**

I am trying to get the [demo code for keycloak-connect library to run](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_nodejs_adapter), but failing.

Here's what I did:

- Download and start keycloak 4.7 standalone, set admin user and pw
- Create a basic public client
- [image: client config]
- Create a user
- [image: Demo User]
- Create a basic express app in webstorm
- Relevant files:

index.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');


var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var session = require('express-session');
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');

var memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();

let keycloak = new Keycloak({ store: memoryStore });

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

app.set('trust proxy', 1); // trust first proxy
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true },
    store: memoryStore
}));

app.use( keycloak.middleware() );

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.get('/$', function(req, res) {
    res.write('<a href="/secure">Secure</a>');
    res.end();
});

app.get( '/secure', keycloak.protect('realm:master'), function(req, res){
//Edit: keycloak.protect() gives the same result
    res.write("Yo!");
    res.end();
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

keycloak.json (copy/paste)

```
{
  "realm": "master",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "test",
  "public-client": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "keycloak-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "keycloak-connect": "^4.7.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "pug": "2.0.0-beta11"
  }
}
```

**Problem:**

On accessing `http://localhost:3000/secure`, I am redirected to the keycloak login form, and can log in with the user credentials for the demo user.

I am then redirected back to `/secure`, and the website says `Access denied` with `403 forbidden` response code.
The keycloak console says

```
16:44:56,691 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-8) 
type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, 
realmId=master, 
clientId=test, 
userId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, 
ipAddress=127.0.0.1, 
error=invalid_code, 
grant_type=authorization_code, 
code_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, 
client_auth_method=client-secret
```

[image]

The node.js console says `Could not obtain grant code: 400:Bad Request`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: were you able to make it work out??

Answer (score 0):

you are securing your resource `/secure` with a realm role called `master`

> app.get( '/secure', keycloak.protect('realm:master')

you need to create master role and assign to `demouser` as shown below

[image]

Comment: I added a "user" role, like in your screenshot, which did not work. I also added a role named "master" which did not work as well.
The error alos persists if I do not put a parameter to the "protect()" method.
Can you please specify?
You write "create master role",m but in the screenshot there is no role "master".

Comment: It should be master role because you have keycloak.protect('realm:master')

Comment: It gives the same error with master role, and when I remove the 'realm:master' from keycloak.protect()

Comment: update the screenshot, You can try out example give in quickstarts https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/service-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

If you are running keycloak and also your backend in Docker, the keycloak url won't be localhost anymore in the config file. Your backend will try to reach its own localhost, which has a different IP address under Docker. You can check the networking settings of Docker to create a common network for your backend and keycloak, or serve both to your host machine and change auth-server-url as shown.

```
const keycloakConfig = {
  'confidential-port': 0,
  'auth-server-url': 'http://host.docker.internal:8080/auth',
  resource: 'my-client-id',
  'ssl-required': 'external',
  realm: 'my-realm',
  credentials: {
    secret: 'my-secret',
  },
};
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem with this is a problem with the npm keycloak-connect package, when you install using npm install must be getting a warning which says, run npm audit.

Run npm audit --force abd rerun the app it will work. I was stuck in the same problem for a day and this thing came as a life saver for me.

run npm audit --force  after an npm install.

npm install

npm audit --force

Comment: It's related to the code and keycloak configuration, _not_ the package version. I got the same error with or without the auditing.